# Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol when trying to clone a repo in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to clone a repo in R with the `git2r` package by doing

```
library(git2r)
repo <- path.expand("~/dev/test/repo_name")
git2r::clone("git@github.com:eecs442/utils.git", repo)
```

but getting

```
Error in git2r::clone("git@github.com:eecs442/utils.git", repo) : 
  Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `repo` is the variable name of your local directory string you want to clone to, it should be

```r
library(git2r)
clone("https://github.com/eecs442/utils", repo)
```

For a private repository, you can do

```r
clone("https://user:password@github.com/eecs442/utils", repo)
```

Comment: This worked! How come using an https link works when I'm being authenticated via ssh?

Comment: @HarryM Not sure what you mean. `clone` requires a full URL and the repo in question is a public repository. Cloning a public repo does not require any authentication.

Comment: Oh I actually tried a URL of this format (https://) for a private repo and it worked as well. I thought when cloning from a private repo to which I'm authenticated via SSH, I should use the link formatted like `git@github.com:repo/utils.git` but surprised that using the `https://` link also works

Comment: @HarryM By *"to which I'm authenticated via SSH"* do you mean you've set up and added a private SSH key to your private repo?

Comment: @HarryM I've made an edit to clarify how to use `clone` with a private repo. The first argument of `clone` needs to be a full URL, so you need the `https://`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have an SSH key set up and just directly using `clone("https://github.com/repo_name/utils", repo)` worked

Comment: Actually it didn't work for a private repo cloning via SSH. I posted a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176959/getting-unsupported-url-protocol-when-using-ssh-authentication-with-git2rclo?noredirect=1#comment106439379_60176959

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207620/discussion-between-maurits-evers-and-harry-m).