# Getting `unsupported URL protocol` when using SSH authentication with git2r::clone in R

Tags: r, git, ssh

I'm trying to clone a private repo with git2r::clone **via SSH** (not HTTPS protocol) in R by doing

`git2r::clone("git@git.server.com:team_name/repo_name.git", "~/dev/")`

but, I keep getting

`Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol`

What could be wrong?

I am authenticated to the repo via SSH and can clone using the same URL in the command line with `git clone url`. I would like to avoid using https and entering my credentials into the URL.

I made sure to install `libssh2` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599858/how-to-push-git-repository-through-ssh-using-git2r?rq=1)

Comment: Did you also have it installed before git2r was compiled? And which platform are you using?

Comment: Not sure. How can I force it to recompile? I'm on MacOS

Comment: I would start with a simple uninstall and reinstall, but it really depends on how you installed it in the first place

Comment: try providing the protocol explicitely: `ssh://git@git.server.com:team_name/repo_name.git`

Comment: Just tried both uninstalling and reinstalling and adding `ssh://` in the URL and both still gave the same error

Comment: @HarryM This definitely works for a private repo: `clone("https://user:password@github.com/eecs442/utils", "test")`

Comment: @HarryM I'm closing this question as a duplicate of your previous one. I'm giving an example on how to clone from a private repo in my answer there. Notice the position of your GitHub ID and password in the full URL.

Comment: It works over https, but I would like to clone via SSH without having to enter the username and password into the URL

Comment: The second question is different because it's about cloning over SSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if your git2r installation does not support SSH and therefore can't parse git SSH URLs.

You can confirm by running
`libgit2_features()` in R.

If SSH is disabled, you will see

```
$threads
[1] TRUE

$https
[1] TRUE

$ssh
[1] FALSE
```

To fix this, make sure you have installed `libssh2` and `libgit2`. In my case, I had `libssh2`, but I was still missing `libgit2`. On a Mac, you can do

`brew install libssh2` and `brew install libgit2`.

After that, re-install git2r from source with

`install.packages("git2r", type="source", configure.vars="autobrew=yes")`

Reload git2r with `library(git2r)`. Now if you run `libgit2_features()` in R, you should see `ssh TRUE`